# how to groupby-apply-aggregate back to a dataframe in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
def my_per_group_func(temp):

    # apply some tricks here
    return a, b, c, d

output =  dataframe.groupby('group_id').apply(my_per_group_func)
```

my question here is how to aggregate "output" back to a dataframe with some column names (obviously the index of the dataframe is group_id)?

normally what i do is to use the aggregate function

but the problem here is that the my_per_group_func is very complicated here, it cannot be done using the normally 'aggregate' function syntax

does anyone have a clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems need return `DataFrame` or `Series` - check [flexible apply docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply):

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'group_id':[1,1,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (dataframe)
   B  C  D  E  F  group_id
0  4  7  1  5  7         1
1  5  8  3  3  4         1
2  6  9  5  6  3         3

def my_per_group_func(x):
    #print (x)
    #some sample operations
    a = x.B + x.C
    b = x.E + x.B
    c = x.D + x.F
    d = x.F + x.E
    return pd.DataFrame({'group_id': x.group_id, 'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c, 'd':d})

output =  dataframe.groupby('group_id').apply(my_per_group_func)
print (output)
    a   b  c   d  group_id
0  11   9  8  12         1
1  13   8  7   7         1
2  15  12  8   9         3
```

---

```
def my_per_group_func(x):
    #print (x)
    #some sample aggregations
    a = (x.B + x.C).mean()
    b = (x.E + x.B).sum()
    c = (x.D + x.F).median()
    d = (x.F + x.E).std()
    return pd.Series([a,b,c,d], index=['a','b','c','d'])

output =  dataframe.groupby('group_id').apply(my_per_group_func)
print (output)
             a     b    c         d
group_id                           
1         12.0  17.0  7.5  3.535534
3         15.0  12.0  8.0       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dataframe['new column name'] = dataframe.groupby('group_id').transform(my_per_group_func)
```

Comment: maybe you can provide some context about your answer and why this would fix the issue?